# How to make a top wrapper(?) with a background color

Tags: html, css

First off, I'm really new to this so sorry if I sound dumb ;_;. Now, I'm trying to make a background color on my list items. Like this site has, black bar with the logo, search bar etc.. I tried wrapping divs everywhere but nothing seems to work.

HTML

```
<nav class="nav-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Staff</li>
            <li>Schedule</li>
            <li>Home</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-menu ul {
margin-right: 50px;
}
.nav-menu li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin-left: 30px;
float: right;
color: red;
}
.container {
color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4KJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `overflow` to `auto` to display everything in the `.content` div (now everything is `hidden` because you use `float` property)

```
.container {
   background: black;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

I guess it is a typo, anyway , you should set `background` property instead of `color` to set background color.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4KJ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

if you only want a background color in each list item you can use this one:

```
.nav-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: right;
    color: red;
    background:#000000;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4KJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a clearfix after your floating element.

html:
put a

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

after your `<ul></ul>`

related css:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

and you would need to change `color: black;` to `background-color: black;` ;-)

see: http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4KJ/4/